# /etc/fstab does not mount automatically on Debian 10

Tags: debian, mount

On all the Linuxes that I've tried before, whenever one puts something in `/etc/fstab` it gets automatically mounted when the machine is restarted, however after installing Debian 10, the same mechanism doesn't seem to work on it.

The fstab entry looks like this:

```
//hostname/Share /Share cifs _netdev,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,username=<NAME>,password=<PASSWORD>,rw,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
```

After restart, the mount folder is empty and is not listed in the mounts. I looked at dmesg, and these are the only mentions of mounts or cifs:

```
[    3.067180] FS-Cache: Netfs 'cifs' registered for caching
[    3.067243] Key type cifs.spnego registered
[    3.067247] Key type cifs.idmap registered
[    3.068769] No dialect specified on mount. Default has changed to a more secure dialect, SMB2.1 or later (e.g. SMB3), from CIFS (SMB1). To use the less secure SMB1 dialect to access old servers which do not support SMB3 (or SMB2.1) specify vers=1.0 on mount.
```

That dialect message doesn't come up at every restart, though.

I had to add `sudo mount -a` to crontab @restart to get them to show up, but is there a more "proper" way for Debian 10 to recognize fstab the way other Debians do?

Comment: What do the logs show?

Comment: add the output of cat /etc/fstab in your answer

Comment: @waltinator added the relevant-seeming logs that I saw

Comment: @Qasim added the fstab entry

Comment: Could you format it correctly too in a code format as you have done with the other example

Comment: Is this the ONLY fstab entry you have in the fstab file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`systemd` will use the contents of the traditional `/etc/fstab` file to dynamically create "mount units". You'll need to check the status of the appropriate mount unit to see why it failed: please run `systemctl status Share.mount`.

The most likely reason is that NetBIOS name resolution isn't available (i.e. Samba's `nmbd` isn't running yet) when the mount attempt happens, as suggested in [the appropriate Debian Wiki page](https://wiki.debian.org/SAMBAClientSetup).

See `man systemd.mount` for systemd-specific mount options you can use in `/etc/fstab`. For example, you might use `x-systemd.automount` as a workaround: with it, systemd should mount the filesystem automatically the first time something attempts to use it.

Also, check `systemctl status network-online.target`: if you have a static network configuration, the system might be failing to detect when the network connection is properly "online", and attempt to mount network filesystems too early as a result. Check the new `WAIT_ONLINE_IFACE=` and `WAIT_ONLINE_METHOD=` settings in `/etc/default/networking` configuration file for possible ways to make the network online detection more reliable.

Also, to silence the dialect message, you should add `vers=N.N` to your mount options. See `man mount.cifs` for the list of `N.N` values available and the corresponding Windows versions. If the server is at least Windows Server 2008R2, you can use `vers=2.1`.

The old protocol version `vers=1.0` was vulnerable to the attack of the infamous WannaCry ransomware in year 2017, and it could not be fixed, so all up-to-date OSs should by now be programmed to hate that version and not use it unless specifically asked to. (If your server still cannot support any of the newer protocol versions, then that server needs to be upgraded.)

Comment: Quote [https://wiki.debian.org/SAMBAClientSetup](https://wiki.debian.org/SAMBAClientSetup): "Note: If you're on Buster, you'll need to add the option `x-systemd.automount` to mount the share on startup."

Comment: That wiki page actually seems to spell out the reason why ordinary mounting of CIFS filesystems fails to work: "Mounting samba shares for easy access by programs does not work out of the box because NetBIOS name resolution isn't set up correctly." That actually makes sense, good link!

Comment: x-systemd.automount works, interestingly, the page says that the issue is due to a name resolution, but I tried it with IP Address and it didn't mount that either

Comment: I'm not a SMB/CIFS protocol guru, but my guess is that the server wants to know *who is trying to access* and queries the client using classic NetBIOS parts of the protocol. But since Samba `nmbd` is not yet running on the client, there is nothing on the client that could supply the answer, and that makes the server unhappy.

Answer (score 5):

Posting this here so it hopefully helps someone. Took me 4+ hours.

On Debian 10 I needed to run:

```
systemctl enable systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
```

I am using fstab parameters:

```
NFS-Server-IP:/FolderName /mnt/FolderName nfs rw,bg,intr,hard,timeo=600,nfsvers=3 0 0
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved the problem with the auto-mount of my nfs mounts as well!

Comment: this is the one that worked!

Comment: Enabling `systemd-networkd-wait-online` also worked correctly in Debian 11.  Using smb here instead of nfs.

Answer (score 1):

If using SysVinit (instead of SystemD) on Debian Buster, it seems both `auto` and `_netdev` are needed in `<options>` field of fstab for it to mount automatically. Also `<pass>` (last field) probably should be `3` and not `0` for consistency reasons if nothing else (but I haven't tested if it fails without that change)

so

```
//hostname/Share /Share cifs auto,_netdev,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,username=<NAME>,password=<PASSWORD>,rw,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue with NFS mounts in `fstab`. It turned out that, on boot, the mounts were attempted when the network was not ready yet.

Simply installing `network-manager` solved the issue.